# java How to GradientPaint a JFreeChart AreaChart

Tags: java, swing, jfreechart, gradient

```
public static JFreeChart createAreaChart(double[] v1) {
        XYSeriesCollection dataset = new XYSeriesCollection();
        XYSeries series1 = new XYSeries("First");
        for (int i=0;i<v1.length;i++){
            series1.add( i,v1[i]);
        }
        dataset.addSeries(series1);

        final JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYAreaChart(
            "XY Area Chart Demo",
            "Domain (X)", "Range (Y)",
            dataset,
            PlotOrientation.VERTICAL,
            true,  // legend
            true,  // tool tips
            false  // URLs
        );

        GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
                0.0f, 0.0f, Color.red, 
                0.0f, 100.0f, Color.blue
            );

        chart.setBackgroundPaint(Color.white);

        final XYPlot plot = chart.getXYPlot();
        plot.getRenderer().setSeriesPaint(0, gp0);
        //plot.setOutlinePaint(Color.black);
        plot.setBackgroundPaint(Color.lightGray);
        plot.setForegroundAlpha(0.99f);
        plot.setDomainGridlinePaint(Color.white);
        plot.setRangeGridlinePaint(Color.white);

        final ValueAxis domainAxis = plot.getDomainAxis();
        domainAxis.setTickMarkPaint(Color.black);
        domainAxis.setLowerMargin(0.0);
        domainAxis.setUpperMargin(0.0);

        final ValueAxis rangeAxis = plot.getRangeAxis();
        rangeAxis.setTickMarkPaint(Color.black);
        rangeAxis.setAutoRange(false);
        rangeAxis.setRange(-5.0, 5.0);

        return chart;

    }
```

I want something like this below. A gradient fill that switches colour slowly as we cross zero line.

I do not understand what I should put in:

```
    GradientPaint gp0 = new GradientPaint(
            0.0f, 0.0f, Color.red, 
            0.0f, 100.0f, Color.blue
        );
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this is to have 3 shapes. One for the yellow line. Another for the green gradient, and a 3rd for the red gradient.

Then you paint the two last shapes independently.

Comment: But how do I "paint" the area under curve, but above the zero line?

Comment: @Akira, the question is related to using the JFreeChart toolset.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a better starting place would be a `XYDifferenceRenderer` have one series stay a zero so that when the second seires passes it the color will change..   Take a look at DifferenceChartDemo1 in JFreeChart.  Put your two different Color GradientPaints in the constructor of the renderer.

Here is the API link the Renderer:
http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/chart/renderer/xy/XYDifferenceRenderer.html